# MySQL Equivalent to PHP Explode()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Suppose, I have a MySQL column in a table with following data

`1,2,3`. Actually, these are `primary_key` of another table. Now, Let me say what I am trying to do.

I would like to explode these using `comma (,)` and want to create a `sub query` to get the information from another table.

I am giving two table data here, hope that will help you to understand properly..

`tableA`

```
------------------------------------
| col1       | col2      | col3    |
------------------------------------
| 1          | Sam       | 50      |
------------------------------------
| 2          | Zor       | 55      |
------------------------------------
| 3          | Sad       | 40      |
------------------------------------
```

`tableB`

```
--------------------------------
| col1       | idFromTableA    |
--------------------------------
| 1          | 1,3             |
--------------------------------
| 2          | 1,2             |
--------------------------------
| 3          | 1,2,3           |
--------------------------------
```

Now, I am querying from `tableB`. Something like following query-

`SELECT * FROM tableB`

I want to pick the `col2` from `tableA` using `idFromTableA`. I know about `GROUP_CONCAT` but I can't understand.

How can I pick `col2` value using `id` stored in `tableB` named `idFromTableA`? I want to explode the value of `idFromTableA` and want to create a sub-query to get the value from `tableA`. 
Can I achieve this with this logic?

**After @Phil's suggestion I am creating another table and storing the data as follows- Is that okay?**

```
mysql> select * from bb_user_branches;
+-------+---------+-----------+
| ub_id | user_id | branch_id |
+-------+---------+-----------+
|     1 |       5 |         1 |
|     2 |       5 |        29 |
+-------+---------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Don't ever do this with a relational database. Please read this for information on how to achieve a *many-to-many* relationship properly - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

Comment: There is no equivalent to `explode()`, nor is one required. You're storing the data the wrong way.

Comment: Actually, scenario is that one person can work in several branch. I am creating a settings table where I am storing the branch ID's. Mainly, What will be the procedure to store the data?

Comment: Yes, so store them in a many-to-many junction table.

Answer (score 2):

Make a *junction table* to facilitate the *many-to-many* relationship, eg

```
CREATE TABLE `tableA_B` (
    a_col1 INT NOT NULL, -- or whatever the data type is for the foreign key
    b_col2 INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (a_col1, b_col1),
    FOREIGN KEY (a_col1) REFERENCES tableA (col1),
    FOREIGN KEY (b_col1) REFERENCES tableB (col1)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

You can then insert the relevant data

```
INSERT INTO tableA_B (a_col1, b_col1) VALUES
(1, 1), (3, 1),
(1, 2), (2, 2),
(1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3);
```

Then you can perform your select...

```
SELECT b.col1, a.col2
FROM tableB b
INNER JOIN tableA_B ab ON b.col1 = ab.b_col1
INNER JOIN tableA a ON ab.a_col1 = a.col1;
```

Optionally, remove the `idFromTableA` column from `tableB`...

```
ALTER TABLE `tableB` DROP COLUMN `idFromTableA`;
```

You may want to try and migrate the comma separated values into your junction table instead of using the `INSERT` statement above. You'd probably want to use a programmable client interface (like PHP + PDO / mysqli) to do this.

Comment: Actually, I would create the junction table before and try to salvage the data but I get the point, +1 :)

Comment: @hank I couldn't think of a way to iterate the comma delimited values for insertion so didn't bother. I suppose you could do it easily enough using PHP or another programmable client interface. I've rearranged the advice in my answer